# Is the pronoun "it" used correctly in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage, pronouns

Is *it* correctly used in the second sentence? Is it clear I am referring to *Online advertising*?

> Online advertising is an ingenious marketing strategy. As time passes by, more and more brands appear to be using **it** to showcase their products.

My teacher said that it isn't correct because it refers back to *time*.

Comment: Ask your teacher for an explanation.

Comment: @user3169 I don't think that the fact that someone has a teacher forbids them from asking questions here! I'll appreciate if you tell me whether there is any rules in that case or not.

Comment: I didn't intend to mean you can't ask here, at all. But at the same time, it's a teacher's responsibility to explain the subject matter, not just say "This is the answer." Actually, I would be curious about the response, since the teacher is wrong.

Comment: @user3169 Well, I am trying to get an IELTS and my teacher is an IELTS teacher, He is not native and non-native teachers sometimes just stick to a rule and do not grasp the idea behind that. He said that although my sentence can be understood, it is wrong in terms of pronoun usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pronoun reference is not really a matter of **correctness.** Some people seem to believe that a pronoun can refer only to the most recent noun phrase that matches in number, gender, and animacy (in the cases of he, she, and it). But this is a false belief, as the following examples illustrate:

> 1. I can't fit the trombone into the suitcase because it is too small.
> 2. I can't fit the trombone into the suitcase because it is too big.

In **1**, we understand that **it** refers to the suitcase because we know that a trombone cannot be **too small** to fit into a container. Only the suitcase can be **too small.**

In **2** we understand that **it** refers to the trombone because we know that a suitcase cannot be **too big** to contain a trombone. Only the trombone can be **too big.**

(Tom Scott addresses all this in a [fun video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3vIEKWrP9Q).)

The point is that position alone does not determine meaning or ambiguity. We understand pronoun reference as a matter of context as well as proximity.

Turning now to your sentence. **Time** is certainly *available* as a referent for **it**. They agree in number, gender, and animacy. But **strategy** is similarly available. The listener asks (unconsciously and with remarkable speed) whether **time** is a meaningful referent and if it is more meaningful than **strategy**.

I think a listener would have to be a fool to infer that **it** refers to **time** in this case. For one thing, it is hard to imagine how **time** can be used to *showcase a product.* For another, **it** is being used by **brands**, which extends the topic of the previous sentence (*marketing*) into the sentence in question.

To recap. It is wrong to believe that the nearest available referent must be *the* referent. Context and meaning play a strong role as well.